# When should I install the Borderlands DLCs?

Tags: borderlands

I have just got Borderlands Game of the Year Edition in the mail today. The game comes with all four DLCs. When should I install these DLCs?

Would I just install the main game, complete it and then install the DLCs one at a time in release order (if that's even possible. Not sure if you need to install all four DLCs)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no disadvantages to installing them all now in any order.

You access the DLCs from the Teleport menu and can completely ignore them until you want to play them. However Mad Moxxie's DLC gives you instant access to a bank to store items in (GREAT for keeping spare guns/COMs) and Knoxx's Armory DLC boosts the level cap by 10 levels just by installing it.

You don't have to play these DLCs at all to get these benefits, though you do have to enter Mad Moxxie's area to store items in the bank, but there are no quests that you have to do to get the bank. You can warp to Moxxie's underdome and store items immediately.

Comment: That's a great answer. There's no reason not to install the DLCs right away, if I can just "skip" them until I have completed the main game. Also, having access to the bank will be great. I will definitely have a look at that. I just tried to install the DLCs. They are lying under "My Games" as "Expansion Pack" without an image and I can't really seem to launch this "Expansion Pack". Will I just put on the "main game" disc and play from the install of the main game? I doubt that the games are installed correctly as the menu screen still says "New DLCs available" or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing to be gained by not installing DLCs before completing the game, and some of them raise the level cap, so it's best to install them immediately after the game itself has been installed.

Comment: Since some of the DLCs raise the level cap, it's good to install them right away so that you don't waste XP by hitting the level cap before installing the DLC.

Comment: @Adeese good point, I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: That's a good point. I'm just afraid that I would mix up the stories of the "main game" with the DLCs.

Comment: @SimonBS: The DLCs add missions accessible only via teleporting to them. You don't really *need* to go into them during the main storyline and can easily avoid doing so.

Answer (score 0):

It depends...

No disadvantages are risen from downloading before the completion of the main game.

But at the same time, you cannot download while playing the game, and they will take their time to download...

I would recommend that you download them while not being active on the xbox, this could include while in the shower, sleeping or even going to the shops, it will add up even if its a few minutes, sure it would be better to do it in one sweet session, but i doubt that will happen.

Comment: I don't think downloading is going to be an issue with a physical copy.

Comment: I thought that you were given and code, which gives you a 'free' download from the marketplace.

Comment: Oh, you may be right.

Comment: Your answer is good. I have a physical 2-disc edition. That wasn't clear from my question, so I believe some (with download codes) might benefit from this answer.